# Trying to update macOS Catalina to Big Sur, stuck after softwareupdate -l

Tags: updates, macos-catalina, macos-bigsur

I have a late 2014 mac-mini.
I need to update from Catalina to Big-Sur so I can install xcode 13, so I can upload builds for iOS.
When I goto system preferences\software update I get "checking for updates" and spinny wheel for hours.

I have also tried entering softwareupdate -l in the terminal, I get the message "finding available software" and then nothing for hours.

My mac has a working internet connection.
Also it is completely stock. I only use it to build for iOS, I have only installed git, unity and xcode on it and I have never done anything else with it or changed any settings.

I have tried the NVRAM fix, booting mac while holding windows key + alt + R + P

I have also reset the mac and my router.

I have also tried downloading big sur directly from the apple.com. When I click the link it opens the app store in the OS. When I click the "get" button for big sur it opens the updater and instead of saying "checking for updates" and then getting stuck for hours it says "finding update" and gets stuck for hours.

I have 700BG free on HDD

I have set DNS to google 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Catalina fixed this. Nothing else I tried had any effect.